# Вопрос по mp3 flash-плеерам

Tags: flash, dom, mp3, actionscript

Ситуация такая:

На страницу сайта на ajax'e подгружается другая страница со списком ссылок на скачивание музыки, встраиваемая в DОМ в блок div "#ajaxContent", на callback'e подвесил функцию, определяющую нужный мне типаж ссылок и встраивающий flash mp3-плееры после каждой подходящей ссылки.Есть такая закорючка,что если пользователь перейдёт по какой-либо из ссылок меню,то содержимое "#ajaxContent" удаляется из DОМ и на его место подгружается другая страница,играющая музыка,естественно,прекращает играть,т.к. флеш-объект прекращает своё существование.Идея такая,при следующем аjах-запросе играющий плеер перенести в статичный блок страницы с сохранением отрезка проигранного времени,чтобы плеер продолжил играть музыку после переноса из блока в блок.

Вопрос первый: возможно ли такое?

Второй вопрос: как это реализовать?что-то вроде локального хранилища данных flаsh сорганизовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перенесите плеер в другой блок. Отдельный. Если пользователь нажмёт на ссылку с музыкой то играем её в плеере.  Если нажмет на меню то блок с плеером не пострадает ...